# XPath getting a specific set of elements within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, xpath

I am scraping Google Scholar and have trouble getting the right XPath expression. When I inspect the wanted elements it returns me expressions like these:

```
//*[@id="gs_res_ccl_mid"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/a[3]
//*[@id="gs_res_ccl_mid"]/div[3]/div/div[3]/a[3]
// *[@id="gs_res_ccl_mid"]/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/a[3]
```

I ended up with the generic expression:

```
//*[@id="gs_res_ccl_mid"]//a[3]
```

Also tried the alternative, with similar results:

```
//*[@id="gs_res_ccl_mid"]/div*/div*/div*/a[3]
```

The output is something like (I can not post the entire result set because I dont't have 10 points of reputation):

```py
[
'https://scholar.google.es/scholar?cites=5812018205123467454&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=es',
'https://scholar.google.es/citations?user=EOc3O8AAAAAJ&hl=es&oi=sra',
'https://scholar.google.es/citations?user=nd8O1XQAAAAJ&hl=es&oi=sra',
'https://scholar.google.es/scholar?cites=15483392402856138853&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=es',
'https://scholar.google.es/scholar?cites=7733120668292842687&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=es',
'https://scholar.google.es/scholar?cites=15761030700327980189&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=es'
]
```

The problem with the output is that there are 3 unwanted elements extras and they all have this piece of text `citations?user`. What can I do to rid me off the unwanted elements?

My code:

```
def paperOthers(exp,atr=None): 
                  
     thread = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH,(" %s" % exp))
   
     xArray = []
    
     for t in thread:
         if atr == 0:
             xThread = t.get_attribute('id')
         elif atr == 1:                
             xThread = t.get_attribute('href')
         else:
             xThread = t.text         
         xArray.append(xThread)  
        
     return xArray
```

Which I call with:

```
rcites = paperOthers("//*[@id='gs_res_ccl_mid']//a[3]", 1)
```

Comment: Solved using another xpath: rcites    = paperOthers(".//*[@class='gs_fl']//a[3]",1)

Answer (score 1):

Change the XPath to exclude the items with text.

```py
rcites = paperOthers("//*[@id='gs_res_ccl_mid']//a[3][not(contains(.,'citations?user'))]",1)
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please accept the answer by clicking on the hallow check mark below the down vote button on the left hand side. Feel free to upvote.

Comment: It doesn't work. The error message is:                                                       Given xpath expression " //*[@id='gs_res_ccl_mid']//a[3][not(contains,'citations?user')]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x8060000d (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPathAll :: line 420"  data: no]

Comment: There was a typo, fixed it can you please check with the updated xpath.

Comment: The error was gone, but no changes about the output. It takes the same 13 lines out.

Comment: Well, I've managed to solve the problem. Thank you.
Basically I am not using the xpath marked by Chrome. It works with:                  rcites    = paperOthers(".//*[@class='gs_fl']//a[3]",1)